# iPhone - Core-plot, scroll CPScatterPlot manually

Tags: iphone, scroll, core-plot

I want to scroll `CPScatterPlot` manually in my code. I am able to scroll plot area but while scrolling `globalXRange & globalYRange` not working properly. I can scroll (manually, with button click) beyond the graph. I want to restrict scroll area, once it reaches to global range.

Here is the code I am using,

```
-(IBAction)moveLineLocation:(id)sender {

    isButtonClicked = TRUE;
    currentTag = [sender tag];

    CPPlotRange *rangeX = plotSpace.xRange;
    CPPlotRange *rangeY = plotSpace.yRange; 

    if([sender tag] == 1) {
        rangeX.location = CPDecimalAdd(rangeX.location, CPDecimalFromFloat(-0.5));
    }
    else if([sender tag] == 2) {
        rangeY.location = CPDecimalAdd(rangeY.location, CPDecimalFromFloat(0.5));
    }
    else if([sender tag] == 3) {
        rangeX.location = CPDecimalAdd(rangeX.location, CPDecimalFromFloat(0.5));
    }
    else {
        rangeY.location = CPDecimalAdd(rangeY.location, CPDecimalFromFloat(-0.5));
    }

    plotSpace.xRange = rangeX;
    plotSpace.yRange = rangeY;

    [graph.axisSet relabelAxes];
    [graph reloadData];
}
```

How can I restrict come over from this problem?

**P.S- In touch events `globalXRange & globalYRange` are working absolutely perfect.**

Thanks

Pratik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of the plot ranges before you modify them:

```
CPPlotRange *rangeX = [plotSpace.xRange copy];
CPPlotRange *rangeY = [plotSpace.yRange copy];
```